# Entropy of Matrix using Matlab

Tags: matlab

Given a matrix **A** with dimension **m x n** and the entries in the matrix lies **[0,1]**
For example

```
A = [0.5 0   0  0.5 0
     0   0.5 0  0   0.5
     1   0   0  0   0]
```

I would like to calculate **sum(sum(a_ij log(a_ij)))**, where **a_ij** is the **i** th row and **j** th col entry in the matrix **A**. Since there exist an 0 entry in the matrix, i always get **NAN** as a result.

How do i consider only non-zero entries to calculate **sum(sum(a_ij log(a_ij)))** [entropy of the matrix].

Comment: I came up with the following matlab code **sum(A(A~=0).*log(A(A~=0)))**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To consider only specific elements of a matrix you can use logical indexing. For example if you only want to select non-zero entries of A you can use `A(A~=0)`. So for your problem the solution can be written:

```
sum(A(A~=0).*log(A(A~=0)));
```

EDIT: wow that is some kind of coincidence, I've just seen your comment after posting this. Well, glad you've worked it out yourself.

Comment: Yeah, i tried it few more times after posting the question. Thanks for your effort.

Comment: Good answer, but depending on the size of `A`, it might be better to store the expression `A~=0` in a temporary variable to avoid calculating it twice.

Answer (score 2):

If it is a very large array:

```
sum(A.*log(A+eps))
```

which should be faster than indexing.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility:

```
x = A(:);
E = x' * log(x + (x==0))
```